# How do I get the total cost of a virtual guest and its associated network options?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get the total cost on the next invoice for a monthly paid virtual guest, including everything (CPU, network, memory etc) except external additional SAN block storage.

The API calls I have tried all fail to return any kind of cost that I can correlate with the IBM Cloud Billing portal values that I am seeing.

For instance, the following call gives me all invoiced items as far as I can tell, but it fails to give me *anything* for the totalRecurringAmount.

```
curl -sL -g -u <user>:<pwd> "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/<accountnumber>/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems.json?objectMask=mask[description,recurringFee,children[invoiceItems[totalRecurringAmount]]]"
```

Another approach I have tried is to do this for a specific virtual guest using this call, which returns lots of interesting things but no cost:

```
curl -sL -g -u <user>:<pwd> "https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/<device id>.json?objectMask=mask[billingItem.id,billingItem.hostName,billingItem.invoiceItem.totalRecurringAmount]"
```

I have been reading the API documentation over and over to no avail. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this example

```
curl -sL -g -u <user>:<pwd> "https:api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/<device id>.json?objectMask=mask[billingItem[children[description,invoiceItem[description,totalRecurringAmount]]]]"
```

the way is children>invoiceItem>totalRecurringAmount.

Comment: This request does not return any cost info. I notice that billingItem.recurringMonths is blank, maybe that is a clue?

Comment: This request does not return any cost info (no totalRecurringAmount entries at all).

Answer (score 0):

To get the nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount and their children invoice too for a specific virtual server use the below request:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/[guestId]/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[nextInvoiceChildren,nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount]]
```

The sum of all the children "recurringFee" should be the "nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount".

Now if you want to get this information through [SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems/)
you can use the following python script:

```
import json

import SoftLayer

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.

USERNAME = 'set me'

API_KEY = 'set me'

# Declare the API client
client = SoftLayer.create_client_from_env(USERNAME, API_KEY)
account_service = client['SoftLayer_Account']

guestId = 11111

invoice_mask = 'mask[nextInvoiceChildren,nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount]'

try:
    response_invoices = account_service.getNextInvoiceTopLevelBillingItems(mask=invoice_mask)
    for invoice in response_invoices:
        if invoice['resourceTableId'] == guestId:
            print(json.dumps(invoice, sort_keys=False, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    """
    If there was an error returned from the SoftLayer API then bomb out with the
    error message.
    """
print("Unable to retrieve the billing invoice item information. "
      % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
```

Replace the guestId data for your guestId.

Comment: This API call gives me only one nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount, which seem to correlate with the memory metric on the "IBM Cloud Billing and Usage" website, but not including the cores or uplink.

Comment: The rest api call that a provided includes the cores and the item children such as uplink. The nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount will give you the virtual server total cost on the next invoice for a monthly, now to get the children next invoices information see the "nextInvoiceChildren" array, each item such as os, uplink, etc has the attribute "recurringFee" this will show you the cost for the next invoice as I explained above.

Comment: This method is not to get the memory metric usage, for this there is another method.

Comment: The single nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount I get seem to correlate *only* with the *Memory* metric in the billing portal, and I get no items in the "nextInvoiceChildren" array that contain a non-zero "recurringFee". I have updated the question to clarify what I mean with "Total cost", which is to include basically everything except additional SAN block storage.

Comment: These are the attributes that shows the next invoice total recurring amount for a vs, if you want to get specific invoices information for some items you have to will your own programming code. Try adding this datatype to the mask invoiceItems[children] like this request: https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/11111/getObject?objectMask=mask[billingItem[nextInvoiceChildren,nextInvoiceTotalRecurringAmount,invoiceItems[children]]]. See the children "recurringFee" data which is the next invoice amount for each item.

Comment: If you are getting the same result open a ticket, they can give you more information about this.